# Движение объекта вместе с камерой Unity 2D

Tags: unity3d

делаю 2D top-down игру на unity. Возникла следующая проблема, у меня осуществляется управление пальцам влево-вправо, есть границы у фона в которые упирается камера по оси Х, главный объект находится по середине экрана и движется по оси Х вместе с камерой, т.е. объект находится по середине камеры. Суть проблемы: при свайпе, например, направо, камера доходит до края фона, и упирается в него, объект так же движется до края, но при свайпе в противоположную сторону, камера и объект начинают двигаться одновременно до достижения следующего края. Подскажите, как сделать, чтобы при свайпе от края в противоположную сторону сначала двигался объект до середины камеры, а затем камера вместе с объектом до противоположного края.
Надеюсь суть проблемы ясна. Спасибо.

Answer (score 0):

```
public float TargetX; // куда смотрим
float HalfCameraWidth = 10; // указать половину ширины камеры
float LeftBorder = 0; // левая граница обзора
float RightBorder = 100; // правая граница обзора

void Update () {
    float NewX = TargetX; // следит за целью
    if (NewX < LeftBorder+HalfCameraWidth)
        NewX = LeftBorder+HalfCameraWidth; // коррекция левого ограничения обзора
    else if (NewX > RightBorder-HalfCameraWidth)
        NewX = RightBorder-HalfCameraWidth; // коррекция правого ограничения обзора
    Vector3 CamPos = Camera.main.transform.localPosition;
    Camera.main.transform.localPosition = new Vector3(NewX, CamPos.y, CamPos.z);
}
```